# In node.js mysql query, check if no matching found

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, node-mysql

How can I check if no matching found in mysql (node.js)?

```
mysql.query("select * from table1 where name = 'abcd'", function(error, result, field) {
    if(error) {
        exist(error); //No error
    } else if(result) {
        console.log(result);  //displays '[]'
        exist(null, result);
    } else {
        exist(null, null); //It is never execute
    }
});
function exist(error, result) {
    if(result)
        console.log("Test:"+result); //Executed and displays 'Test:'
}
```

My database does not contains name = 'abcd'. So, how can I check if the query does not match?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You're receiving an empty array (`[]`) as result of your query, because as you said, *your database does not contain any row with `name = 'abcd'`*.

When you do:

```
if (result) {
  if (result)
    console.log("Test:" + result);
```

, you'll enter the `if`, because JavaScript evaluates `true` for `[]`. Take a look at [this article here](http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/truthy-and-falsy-values-in-javascript.html), that explains how JavaScript evaluates `true` and `false` values.

A better way to check if your result array is empty is to do:

```
if (result.length > 0) {
  if (result)
    console.log("Test:" + result);
```

Comment: `if (!result.length)` will work perfectly fine here.

Comment: @BenFortune Agreed, since Javascript evaluates `false` for `0`. It's just that I like that verbose way of writing code.

Comment: Shouldn't it be ```(if result.isArray() && result.length > 0) ```??   Anyway, Ben's "negative" is better

Comment: @BenFortune It didn't work fine for me. What worked for me is `if(result.length != 0)` or greater than.

Comment: If `result.length` is greater than 0, why do you need to check for `if result`?

Comment: If you are paranoid, then it should be `if (result && result.isArray() && result.length > 0) ...` There are times when the result is `null` but there was no `error` either.

Comment: To validate that the `result` is an array, use: `Array.isArray(result)`