# Check if a uuid (in the database) exists

Tags: javascript, mysql, discord.js

How do I check if a data exists in a MySQL database? I have already managed to get the data but I just want to know how to do it: If this data does not exist.

My current code:

```
connection.query(`select builduhcelo from practiceplayers where uuid = '${uuid}'`, function (errbu, resultbu) {
    if(errbu) throw errbu;
    connection.query(`select nodebuffelo from practiceplayers where uuid = '${uuid}'`, function (errnd, resultnd) {
        if(errnd) throw errnd;
        connection.query(`select ironbuilduhcelo from practiceplayers where uuid = '${uuid}'`, function (erribu, resultibu) {
            if(erribu) throw erribu;
            let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                .setAuthor(`Elorion.net`, `https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/06/7/1549795460-logo-elorionnetwork.png`)
                .setColor(color.elorion)
                .addField("Username", username)
                .addField("UUID", uuid)
                .addField("BuildUHC Elo", resultbu[0].builduhcelo)
                .addField("NoDebuff Elo", resultnd[0].nodebuffelo)
                .addField("IronBuildUHC Elo", resultibu[0].ironbuilduhcelo)
                .addField("Skin", `[Download](https://crafatar.com/skins/${uuid}.png)`)
                .setThumbnail(`https://crafatar.com/avatars/${uuid}.png?size=400&overlay=true`)
                .setFooter(`Ⓒ Elorion.net 2019. All rights reserved`);
            message.channel.send(embed)
        })
    })
})
```

I receive this error when the uuid does not exist in the database:

```
throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors 
^ 

TypeError: Cannot read property 'builduhcelo' of undefined
```

Comment: Your query string has unbalanced back tics, quotes, braces and parentheses.

Comment: @trincot I suppose those were typos as the OP claims to have managed to get the data.

Comment: @jom, It would have been better to let the OP correct that, so that is sure the same is true in their code.

Comment: "select builduhcelo from practiceplayers where uuid = '${uuid}'",`

Comment: Should I reopen it @trincot. Was that Dup a bit too obvious?

Comment: Maybe, @RiggsFolly, I think the OP's question really is answered by  `if (!result.length) ....`, which may be covered by another duplicate.

Comment: Ok, no problem, DONE

Comment: Potential dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24675125/in-node-js-mysql-query-check-if-no-matching-found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are referencing `resultbu[0]` when that `resultbu` will (sometimes) be an empty array, so then `resultbu[0].builduhcelo` is not possible and triggers the error.

Secondly, you are nesting queries that you could have done in one go. Select all three columns in your SQL query.

Finally, add an `if` condition to verify that the `result` array is not empty:

```
connection.query(`select builduhcelo, nodebuffelo, ironbuilduhcelo 
                  from practiceplayers 
                  where uuid = '${uuid}'`, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw errbu;
    if (result.length) { /* Only execute the rest when there is a match: */
        let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setAuthor(`Elorion.net`, `https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/06/7/1549795460-logo-elorionnetwork.png`)
            .setColor(color.elorion)
            .addField("Username", username)
            .addField("UUID", uuid)
            .addField("BuildUHC Elo", result[0].builduhcelo)
            .addField("NoDebuff Elo", result[0].nodebuffelo)
            .addField("IronBuildUHC Elo", result[0].ironbuilduhcelo)
            .addField("Skin", `[Download](https://crafatar.com/skins/${uuid}.png)`)
            .setThumbnail(`https://crafatar.com/avatars/${uuid}.png?size=400&overlay=true`)
            .setFooter(`Ⓒ Elorion.net 2019. All rights reserved`);
        message.channel.send(embed)
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you very, very much.
I was close to the goal when I was doing the tests, I just didn't know where to put it: ```if (result.length)```

Comment: This is a new question, which also enters a different technology (non-SQL). Could you please ask this as a new question? If you formulate it well and tag it correctly, it will soon attract the right audience to it.

Comment: Hello, I recently changed to mongoDB, so how could I do it via mongoose?
My document : http://prntscr.com/mn9fqt
Sorry for the inconvenience, thank you in advance
Sincerely

Comment: Ok no problem trincot